# Проблема с подгружаемыми шрифтами (Downloadable Fonts)

Tags: android, android-resources

Решил в проекте использовать [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html). Реализовал все как рекомендуется с сертификатом, с указанием мета-даты в манифесте и с самим шрифтом. Шрифт лежит в папочке res/font.

Возникла следующая проблема: при попытке получить сам шрифт через **ResourcesCompat**.

```
ResourcesCompat.getFont(MainActivity.this, R.font.roboto_bold)
```

Возникает следующий **exception**:

```
Font resource ID #0x7f090005 could not be retrieved
```

Как решить данную проблему?

*PS:*

1. support-compat библиотека последней версии
2. Вариант решения через **ResourcesCompat.FontCallback** не очень хороший путь
3. Минимальная sdk 16
4. Не работает на девайсах как с **Google Paly Services** так и без них